# Запрос sql выдает ошибку, очень нужна помощь

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO Athletes (Last_Name, First_Name, sex, birth_date, state_id, growth, weight)
VALUES ('Лапшин', 'Тимофей', 'муж','1988-02-03', 5, null, null);

SELECT * FROM Athletes
```

> ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  в записи "new" нет поля "state_name"
> CONTEXT:  SQL-оператор: "SELECT UPPER(NEW.STATE_NAME)"
> функция PL/pgSQL capitalize_names(), строка 3, оператор присваивание SQL state: 42703

Comment: Ну явно проблема в триггере...

Comment: Приведите полный запрос. Возможно, Вы применяете что-то типа ``select id,(a+b) as summa from testtable where summa=12345